# Cannot execute deletion if UserForm activated end of code

Tags: excel, vba

Edit: I revised the userform2 particular code with whole code

I have 2 userforms and userform2 code defined below. My problem is the sheet selected from userform2 combobox (populated from sheet names) to be deleted keep activated if the code eventually shows userform1. But makro works well and deletion becomes successful if I remove the line "UserForm1.Show". How can I delete selected sheet all and show userform1 after a successful execution? Thanks in advance for your help.

Userform2 CODE

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If UserForm2.ComboBox1.Value = "SILINECEK CARIYI SEÇIN" Then
        MsgBox "CARI SEÇMEDINIZ"
        Unload UserForm2
        Application.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ToggleButton1.Value = True And i < 5 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect
        Sheets("MASTER CARI").Visible = True
        Worksheets(UserForm2.ComboBox1.Text).Delete
        Unload UserForm2
        Application.Visible = False
        UserForm1.Show
        ActiveWorkbook.Protect
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect
        Worksheets(UserForm2.ComboBox1.Value).Delete
        Unload UserForm2
        Application.Visible = True
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you hiding the whole application? `Application.Visible = False`

Comment: Are the Userforms `Modal` or `Modeless` forms?  (check the `ShowModal` property).  What happens when it doesn't work?  (is Excel hidden/still running in the task explorer? Is `Userform1` waiting for input, but not visible?)